# How to save entity with a foreign key referencing itself (recursive foreign key) in TypeORM

Tags: database, foreign-keys, psql, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I'm new to TypeORM and I'm stuck in a chicken/egg scenario. I have the following entity:

```
@Index("institutes_pkey", ["idInstitute"], { unique: true })
@Entity("institutes", { schema: "public" })
export class Institutes {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: "bigint", name: "id_institute" })
  id_institute: string;

  @Column("text", { name: "name" })
  name: string;

  @Column("text", { name: "description" })
  description: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Institutes, (institutes) => institutes.institutes)
  @JoinColumn([{ name: "id_grupo", referencedColumnName: "idInstitute" }])
  id_group: Institutes;

  @OneToMany(() => Institutes, (institutes) => institutes.id_group)
  institutes: Institutes[];
}
```

*child_institutes* can be grouped under the umbrella of a bigger *father_institute*.

In that case the the id groups would look like this:

`father_institute.id_group = father_institute.id_institute`

`child_institutes.id_group = father_institute.id_institute`.

If a institute won't be part of any group, it's id_group equals it's id_institute (same as father case). And here lies my issue, when I need to save a *father_institute*, it's FK references the very same object I'm trying to save. What can I do in that case?

I imagined a workaround, create a sequence in PSQL and set id_institute with that sequence then set the default value of id_group to the current value of this sequence. But is there any better solution for this?